# AdMob ads not showing from a function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have made an android app using Android Studio and I have implemented Google AdMob into it.

However, when it comes to showing ads, whenever I try to show it from a function, it does not show.

**Here is the function:**

```
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.jodastudios.universalskyremote", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int clicks = sharedPreferences.getInt("clicks", 0);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("clicks", 0);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
    }
```

Whenever I show the ads on the OnCreate method, they show.

**Here is the code:**

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.jodastudios.universalskyremote", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int clicks = sharedPreferences.getInt("clicks", 0);
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("clicks", 0);
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
                }
            }
        },9000);
```

I don't know why the ads are not showing from a function: does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second code is delayed for 9 sec and that's enough time for the ad to load.

Function cannot display ad that has not been loaded!

You have to set AdListener and show add from onAdLoaded method or create callback to show from activity...

**...or call your function from onAdLoaded(){**

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(adIdent);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            interstitialAd.show();

            //TODO or create callback to show from activity
            if (adCallback != null) {
                adCallback.onAdLoaded();
            }
        }
        
        .....................
        .....................
        
    }
```

and

```
interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```